# Installing Devise: `PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: relation "users" does not exist`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Here's what I did successfully to install Devise:

- I put in the devise gem
- Ran `bundle install`
- Installed devise with `rails generate devise:install`
- Ran `rake db:migrate` (successfully) just to be safe

Now when I try to do `rails generate devise User` I get the following error:

```
== 20190915133638 AddDeviseToUsers: migrating =================================
-- change_table(:users)
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist
: ALTER TABLE "users" ADD "email" character varying DEFAULT '' NOT NULL
```

I tried this adding a few custom fields to the devise migration, but then again with the autogenerated migration and got the same result either way.

Can anyone see how I'm getting this error?  I've tried `rake db:reset db:create db:migrate` but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you have a `User` model before? It seems that devise thought that too and it's trying to add its columns to a non-existent `User` model.

This is what I would do...

1. Run `rails db:drop`
2. Delete `db/schema.rb` file.
3. Delete `db/migrate/20190915133638_add_devise_to_users.rb`
4. Run `rails generate devise:install` again
5. Run `rails db:migrate`

**EDIT**

If the previous steps didn't work then try to create a `users` table before devise's migration.

For this follow these steps:

1. `rails g model User`
2. Change the name of the migration file so it will be executed right before the `AddDeviseToUsers` migration.
3. Run `rails db:migrate`

Comment: Nope, even with the addition of deleting the `schema.rb` I still get the same error.  And this is a brand new app.  Literally creating my first model.

Comment: This update is great.  It worked to get the database created, but now I get an `undefined method 'devise' for User (call 'User.connection' to establish a connection):Class` error on the User Model line that says `devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable`

Comment: Run `rails generate devise:install` again.

Comment: Unfortunately I did, without a change in results.  I think this has to be the piece that's malfunctioning.  Would uninstalling and reinstalling the gem do anything?  I can't see that it would....

Answer (score 0):

Try `db:drop` instead of `db:reset`

Comment: Tried this as well with the same results.

Comment: The provided answer was flagged for review as a Low Quality Post.  Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  This provided answer is not correct and code only answers are not considered "good" answers.  From [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/24054670).